# Issue running 32-bit executable on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit, 32bit-64bit, wkhtmltopdf

**I'll add 500 of my own rep as a bounty when SO lets me.**

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert HTML web pages to PDFs. This works perfectly on my 32-bit dev server [unfortunately, I can't ship my machine   :-p  ]. However, when I deploy to the web application's 64-bit server the following errors are displayed:
    (running from cmd.exe)

```
C:\>wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf
Loading pages (1/5)
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()            ] 10%
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()            ] 36%
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
// ...etc....
```

and the PDF is created and saved... just WITHOUT text. All form-fields, images, borders, tables, divs, spans, ps, etc are rendered accurately...just void of any text at all.

Server information:

```
    Windows edition: Windows Server Standard Service Pack 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon    E5410 @ 2.33GHz 2.33 GHz
    Memory: 8.00 GB
    System type: 64-bit Operating System
```

**Can anyone give me a clue as to what is happening and how I can fix this?**

*Also, I wasn't sure what to tag/title this question with...so if you can think of better tags/title comment them or edit the question. :-)*

Comment: Are you running the application as a service?

Services don't always have access to the screen so getting the text metrics of a font might fail then.

Try running the application interactively and see if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure. How do I do that?

Comment: Are there different binaries for 64 and 32 bit? In case you don't know, you can run 32 bit binaries on your server.
Also, perhaps the server is missing a font that is needed.

Comment: There is an installer for windows....so I used that and it defaulted to installing to /Program Files (x86). So I think there is just the 32-bit version.

Comment: I checked the fonts and they are there. It fails with the same error msgs even when loading a text file.

Comment: I'm thinking the production server just needs to be restarted as fonts don't display for Internet Explorer either. I'll have them do that tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the correct answer was just to restart the Production server. Some font-service must have silently crashed for some unknown reason. May this be a lesson to us all.