# IIS output results "QFontEngineWin failure" when running wkhtmltopdf process from PHP

Tags: php, iis, windows-10, wkhtmltopdf

My IIS server when running php script results `QFontEngine failure`.

Basically I have laravel web app that generates pdf from html, which uses something like this behind the scenes

```
<?php 

use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('wkhtmltopdf --lowquality "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\test.html" "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\test.pdf"', null, null);
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

If run the following script via IIS web server the output of this command is as follows:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
[> ] 0%
[======> ] 10%
[==============================> ] 50%
QFontEngine::loadEngine: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
QFontEngineWin: GetTextMetrics failed ()
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6) 
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6) 
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6) 
Printing pages (6/6)
[> ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
```

If I run this script inside terminal like so `php index.php` there are no errors such as QFontEngine failure and job is successful.

I have checked this issue "[Issue running 32-bit executable on 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812478/issue-running-32-bit-executable-on-64-bit-windows)" but my font service is working so I don't even know where else to look for resolution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"but my font service is working"_ - Isn't it that service that gives you those errors? Also, did you try the solution from that post?

Comment: The error output comes from an application called wkhtmltopdf. I checked my font service and it is running without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I know from Linux distros that wkHtmlToPdf has two compiled forms: one that works without a graphic terminal ("headless"), and one which doesn't. I can assume that you have the one that doesn't work without a graphic terminal and that the IIS environment is running wkhtmltopdf in windowless mode (i.e. without a graphic terminal). Have you tried the binaries on https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html ? The missing metrics is consistent with not having a display context to get metrics for.

Comment: I tried 32/64 bit version but its kind of irrelevant as they only have two versions for windows.

Comment: If both these don't work, you have two options: try to run wkhtml as a desktop process (maybe starting from this discussion: https://forums.iis.net/t/1233510.aspx) or take the question to https://wkhtmltopdf.org/support.html and see if they have running headless on windows figured out.

Comment: I used to work before. It started doing that recently for no apparent reason.

Comment: If I run it from terminal it works without a glitch.

Comment: Yes, but the terminal is a windowed desktop process, it has display context. IIS doesn't have a window/desktop context.

Comment: Well but it is started by php in the background, from inside the script. And not directly from a terminal.

Comment: Check comment above, try both MSVC and MinGw versions.

Comment: I tried all of them already. I think I will try it on another machine and see if it works.

Comment: If it is intermittent (it appeared out of nowhere), there is this thread that suggests there may be an error with the "default font" (whatever that means): https://bugs.launchpad.net/mixxx/+bug/1090535 , so you can try troubleshooting font problems... Maybe you changed some fonts in the HTML to be converted, or updated some system fonts or IIS can't access the fonts for some reason...